# Search form genre/keyword

Tags: html

How do I make a form that searches for given keywords such as different genres?
 For example I got 5 buttons, each with a different genre such as Action, Drama, Horror... When I click on the Action it searches for the Action genre in my server and only shows results which contain "Action" in it? For example it can show a result which is Action but also horror...

Looking at w3school the closest I get is radio or checkbox... which isn't what I want...

My form, basically click the genre I want and I get books, music, movies which are of that genre. Thanks

```
   <form action='Search.php' method='GET'>
    <center>
        <h1> Search</h1>
            <input type='text' size='70' name='search'></br></br>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' ></br>
    </center>
</form>
```

Comment: What do the HTML5 and jQuery tags have to do with your question?

Comment: Jquery was suggested and the form is in html isn't it?
Deleted the Jquery, It was suggested so I thought it must been right :P

Comment: `<center>` is not supported in HTML5, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp . Use HTML tag instead of HTML5

Comment: ok changed to html tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical way to do this is to have multiple checkboxes, then you can manipulate the design to make it look like buttons

Here is a minimalist example for you to elaborate on. What this code does, is to hide the input, style the label as a button, then make it interact with the input if checked.

For this to work:

- The Label tag should be right after the input
- Assign IDs to inputs, and match them on the labels

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chb1"/>
        <label for="chb1">Action</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chb2"/>
        <label for="chb2">Drama</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chb3"/>
        <label for="chb3">Comedy</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: 0;
    text-align: center
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #690;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background: #309;
}
```

Tested on JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vkq3ow90/